# extjs4 grid - changing column editor per row basis

Tags: editor, grid, field, extjs4

ExtJS4 grid anticipates appropriate editor (cellEditor or rowEditor) per column.
If a column's header field is dateField - date selector will be applied on every row in that column.

What I need is an editor with different field editors per row, not per column.

The Extjs3 solution is provided [here](http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/changing-columns-editor-dynamically-in-extjs-roweditor/) - unfortunately doesn't fit in Extjs4 case.
(please check that link to see explanatory images, cause I can't post images yet)

There's also a single column solution called [property grid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/property.html), but again - it supports only one column and is very deviated from the standard Ext.grid component

I have tried manually changing grid editor by customizing column.field and reloading grid.editingPlugin.editor, but always get a blank rowEditor panel with no fields.

```
//by default rowEditor applies textField to all cells - I'm trying to force custom numberFiled on apropriate row
var numberField=Ext.form.field.Number();
grid.columns[0].field=numberField;
//destroy current rowEditor's instance 
delete grid.editingPlugin.editor;
//now, upon doubleClick on apropriate cell it should reinitialize itself (initEditor()) - and it does, but is an empty panel
```

what am I missing here? once I delete editingPlugin.editor everything should start from the beginning like during the first time rowEditor is called, but it looses all the fields

Comment: nevermind, did it myself:
[link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?139440-changing-columnEditor-per-row-basis&p=624107#post624107)

Answer (score 4):

**Solution for Ext4:**

I was looking for a solution for this and this guy said the property grid has this behavior.
I have adapted it to work in a clean way for me
on initComponent I declared:

```
this.editors = {
'date'    : Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', { field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date',   {selectOnFocus: true})}),
'string'  : Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', { field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text',   {selectOnFocus: true})}),
'number'  : Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', { field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Number', {selectOnFocus: true})}),
'int'  : Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', { field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Number', {selectOnFocus: true})}),
'boolean' : Ext.create('Ext.grid.CellEditor', { field: Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    editable: false,
    store: [[ true, 'Sim' ], [false, 'Não' ]]
})})
};
```

I used these functions to help me (copied):

```
this.renderCell = function(val, meta, rec) {
    var result = val;
    if (Ext.isDate(val)) {
        result = me.renderDate(val);
    } else if (Ext.isBoolean(val)) {
        result = me.renderBool(val);
    }
    return Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(result);
};

this.getCellEditor = function(record, column) {
    return this.editors[record.get('type')];
};
```

And finally, associate these functions to the column:

```
{text: "Valor", name : 'colunaValor', width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'valor', width:200,
    renderer: Ext.Function.bind(this.renderCell, this),
    getEditor: Ext.Function.bind(this.getCellEditor, this)
}
```